# Delphi7 > Import Type Library (TLB) for MSMQ 3.0 FAIL. "Element not found" error

Tags: windows, delphi, com, delphi-7, msmq

I am trying to create unit from `Delphi7 > Project > Import Type Library` from mqoa.tlb or mqoa.dll, both on WinXP and on Win2003, and even more on Win7x64 (both mqoa30.tlb and mqoa.tlb (or *.dll), which stands for MSMQ 4.0) - every time it fails with error "**Element not found**".

According to MSMQ releases, on Windows 2003 and Windows XP "MSMQ 3.0" is installed, but in my old project I have `MSMQ_TLB.pas` generated from mqoa20.tlb ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\mqoa20.tlb"). I want to switch to MSMQ 3.0 Interfaces, but I cannot.

Any suggestions?

---

By the way, once upon a time I found on internet MSMQ Delphi Example, using MSMQ_TLB.pas generated, probably for MSMQ 3.0, here is snippet from *TLP.pas header:

```
// Type Lib: C:\WINDOWS\system32\MQOA.DLL (1)
// LIBID: {D7D6E071-DCCD-11D0-AA4B-0060970DEBAE}
// LCID: 0
// Helpfile: 
// HelpString: Microsoft Message Queue 3.0 Object Library
// DepndLst: 
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb)
```

I do not know if I can use it reliable in my project, replacing old one *TLB.pas (file uploaded [here](http://www.filedropper.com/msmqtlb), project [here](http://www.milosev.com/index.php/21-delphi/msmq/90-deploying-msmq-30-applications-with-dcom)).

Please advice - I am in total confusion what and how to use.

Comment: I gave a shot with mqoa30.tlb in 'x86_microsoft-windows-msmq-com-common...' on a W7x64 machine, D7 successfully imported msmq_tlb when ran as administrator (when ran as normal user, it told something like 'unable to reach ole registry').

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, D7 is Delphi7? 
I also did it, with Run as Admin and XP compatibility mode on W7x64. 
What do you mean 'x86_microsoft-windows-msmq-com-common...', please more details.

Comment: D7 is Delphi 7. That's the location of the file where I found 'mqoa30.tlb' in, the full path was: 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-msmq-com-common_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_8498010baf76fdc3'.

Comment: The same "Element not found" error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeed doing it by installing newer version of Delphi (in my case - Delphi 2007): 
Main menu > Component > Import Component > Import Type Library...

After this, generated file(s) MSMQ_TLB.PAS (and *.dcr) are usable for Delphi 7 too.